# RubyMine reformatting

Tags: rubymine

This is in the RubyMine IDE.

It seems really simple but I can't find a way to do it. I want to take a line

```
[:a, :b, :c]
```

and as part of the reformatting rearrange each value to one line like so:

```
[
  :a,
  :b,
  :c
]
```

And assign a nice little keyboard shortcut.

Any idea how I do this? RubyMine documentation isn't great.

Comment: if it's possible (not a RubyMine user here) then it will be part of **Code Style** -- check there for Ruby language (at least this is where similar option can be found for PHP, for example -- on `Wrapping & Braces` tab). As to separate shortcut -- there will be no separate shortcut as there will be no separate action just for such transformation -- just use usual `Code | Reformat Code...`

Comment: You could change your ruby code style in the preferences and hit `Ctrl+Alt+L` / `Cmd+Alt+L`

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with a way to use the IDE reformatter for this need.

But, you can achieve the rearrangement using the find an replace tool (CTRL + R).
Mark the regex checkbox.
In the find box look for space - ().
In the replace box, insert newline - `\n\t`.
Then hit Replace all - it should do most of the job.